# Crear Código HTML desde C# en la vista

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de facturación, y tengo una vista creando la factura y su respectivo detalle.

Necesito que cuando el usuario de clic en el botón Agregar Producto, Repita todo el código tr Registrodeproducto

```
                <tr id="Registrodeproducto">
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("Producto", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Selecione el Producto" })</td>                        
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumeroFactura, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm", placeholder = "Referencia", @readonly = 1, @required = 1 })</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumeroFactura, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm", placeholder = "Cantidad", @required = 1 })</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumeroFactura, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm", placeholder = "Precio Venta Unitario", @required = 1 })</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumeroFactura, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm", placeholder = "Subtotal", @readonly = 1, @required = 1 })</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" title="Agregar Producto"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" title="Eliminar Producto"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></span></a>                           
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

He intentado de varias formas pero no lo logro....

Codigo HTML generado por la aplicación:

```
        <div class="container" id="DetalleFactura">
            <table class="table">

                <tr class="active">
                    <th>
                        Producto
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Referencia
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Cantidad
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Precio
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Subtotal
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Acciones
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><select class="form-control input-sm" id="Producto" name="Producto" placeholder="Selecione el Producto"><option value="101">Cocacola 350</option>
```

Camisa

Comment: Ese es un problema que debes atacar desde Javascript, no desde C#. Si tienes un ejemplo del código que te genera el servidor sería de ayuda.

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider Ya edite la pregunta con el código Generado por la aplicacion final